# Is there a Java gui code to choose from different frames?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I mean I have a frame with a button w/ action listener and 4 different frames. When I click the button it will randomly open one of those 4 frames. For example is I have frame 1,2,3,4. If I click my button it will randomly show one of those frames via setVisible(true) i've already set the code to make it visible and make the current frame invisible my only problem is that I don't know how the button will randomly pick from 4 frames

Comment: `(int)(Math.round(Math.random() * 3))` should return a random value between 0-3.  All you need from there is either an `array` containing each frame or a `switch` or `if` statement to implement the logic of showing the frame

Comment: Don't use 4 child frames. Instead use JDialogs. An application should generally only have a single main frame.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random number in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java)

Answer (score 1):

Add all your frames into [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or Array. Create [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) object and generate random number between [0, 3]. Now, where you have list with frames and random number generator you are able to use it. For example:

```
frames.get(random.nextInt(frames.size()));
```

frames - List of all frames
random - instance of [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

See also:

- [Generate random numbers](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62).
- [Use standard Collections](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=9).
- [Prefer Collections over older classes](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=39)

Comment: You might also want to suggest a switch statement

Comment: Yes, it a good thought. But I prefer to use collection instead of switch statement. It more elegant for me. In the case when we want to add few new frames we can add it only to list and this all. Big switch is not readable for me.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help, but this is too hard for me so I decided that i'll just make those four frames have their own button to show them and just put the buttons on the first frame